# Datatable to Generic List Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics

I want to create a **Generic function** to which I pass Model/ViewModel class and that function will convert **Datatable to the List** of that Model/ViewModel, I have tried the following code **but it gives me an error for Null values**, which I have mentioned below.

```
public static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)
{
    List<T> data = new List<T>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        T item = GetItem<T>(row);
        data.Add(item);
    }
    return data;
}
private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
{
    Type temp = typeof(T);
    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
        {
            //if (column.ColumnName == "CreatedOn" || column.ColumnName == "ModifiedOn")
            //    continue;

            if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
                if(dr[column.ColumnName] != null)
                    pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
    return obj;
}
```

Calling:

```
public List<WordInfo> GetData()
{
    DataTable data = _wordsDL.Get("GetAll");
    return Helper.ConvertDataTable<WordInfo>(data);
}
```

> Object of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check for [`DBNull.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=netframework-4.8) instead, something like this:

```
if (dr[column.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value)
    pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);
```

Or:

```
pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : 
      dr[column.ColumnName].ToString(), null);
```